# iCloud storage full, how to empty on icloud.com

Tags: icloud

On https://www.icloud.com/storage/ it says that I've got no space left in the free tier: *Free 0 Bytes • Used 5 GB*. The amount of space that supposedly is being used is even larger, topping out at slight more than 9GB. *Documents - All files 9.1 GB, 181.1% of total storage*.

However, when I go to https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/ to check the content, it contains exactly one image and one pdf for a total of around 5MB.

I previously did delete a bunch of folder/files from here and also turned on icloud drive on my macbook to see if it would somehow show additional files, but only the image and pdf were shown here.

I feel that I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: You may need to wait for the iCloud processes to update information - been caught like that with other sserver storage systems.

Comment: Do you back up an iPhone or an iPad to iCloud?

Comment: No, nothing is being backed up except keychain and passwords. ICloud Drive is disabled. No IPhones or IPads. Could be that I have to wait for it to update, just like @SolarMike suggested.

Comment: On an iPhone/iPad, go to Settings -> Your iCould Account -> iCloud -> Manage Account Storage. You should have a breakdown list of what is taking up the space on your iCloud Drive.

Comment: @StevenKuipers, it should update immediately. Try disabling all of iCloud, sign out of it on your Mac completely (delete the account), restart and sign in again.  Let me know what happens. .